# Estimating the gaze using pupil and glint xy coordinates

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, human-computer-interface, eye-tracking

I have managed to track the center x y coordinate and the radius of the pupil using opencv.

Now I want to measure the gaze using it.

If somebody can help me with the theory part of it, probably I will be able to code it.

Any open source program will also do.

**Update :** I am able to track a glint on the cornea also now. According to my online research the coordinates of the pupil is compared with the glint to estimate the gaze. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Looks to me like you just answered your own question.

Comment: @John But how do I deduce the gaze from it?

Comment: I think the question might be a nice fit for dsp.stackexchange.com, if you would expand on your question a little and give a little more information. Don't cross-post however, when you improve your question, flag it if you think it's better suited there. I'm sure you'll get better responses.

Comment: @penelope Thanks for the lead. I will post it there.

Comment: @anirudh65024x Once more, please, *do not cross-post* Flag you post and moderators will move it. Note that *nobody will want to move* low quality posts (as they will not get enough attention on either site) so make sure to include more information in the post.

Comment: @penelope Alright, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Do you know the location of the illuminator on the cornea?

Comment: @John. Do you mean the glint? Yes, Im able to locate it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the location of the light, not the glint from the light.  Looks like the lack of references would make for a good undergraduate paper.  If you are an undergraduate, I can hook you up with an appropriate journal.

Comment: @John Actually I do have the location of the illuminatior. I am a undergraduate. It would be great if you could hook me up with any journal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got some lead, from SO itself -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454006/1458387

Comment: Hi, I am implementing the same kind of application , so far i have  done accurate pupil detection  , Can you please provide codes or materials to calculate gaze point on the screen